# How to connect multiple bezier curves?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, bezier

I'd like to draw a diagram using `bezierCurveTo()`. As far as I know, it is only possible to set 3 anchor points with 1 `bezierCurveTo()`. If I use multiple of them, I get an unsmooth line. How can I solve this?

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="600" height="150" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;"></canvas>

<script>
  var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

  context.beginPath();
  context.moveTo(0, 150);
  context.bezierCurveTo(100, 0, 200, 100, 300, 20);
  context.bezierCurveTo(400, 0, 500, 100, 600, 20);
  
  context.strokeStyle = 'blue';
  context.stroke();
</script>
```

Comment: The command is "curveTo", it automatically starts at whatever point you're already on, so you just need to guarantee C1 continuity by making the control point of the new curve be on the same line as the control point and last point of the previous curve. Give https://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/#polybezier a read-through for more information (and probably answers to questions that'll pop up later)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a non-trivial problem. It depends on how much smoothness you would like to achieve (just connect tangents, or make curve radiuses in the connection point the same). The simplest way is shown on picture ([A3-X] / [X-B2] = [A3-A4] / [B1-B2]; start [A3-X] vector from A4 and [X-B2] from B1 to get A3x and B2x anchor points).
[image]

But you could also have a look at [D3 Shape module](https://github.com/d3/d3-shape#curves) (e.g. Catmul Rom curve), it will generate you a Bezier spline from points it should go through. Or look at the algorithm somewhere.

Comment: it's actually an entirely trivial problem: given curves `B1` and `B2`, all you need to do is set `B2.c1` to `a * B1.e - B1.c2` where `a` is some arbitrary non-zero positive constant, and `e` is the on-curve end point. That gets you C1 continuity; set `a=1`, now you even have C2 continuity.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans No, it's not trivial, there are many use cases, where different algorithm is needed. E.g. one for drawing app (I've spent several years for Inker graphics editor's algorithm), other for road construction (Euler spiral), another for chart (here is my algorithm for Taucharts library https://github.com/TargetProcess/tauCharts/blob/master/src/utils/path/interpolators/smooth.ts#L21).

Comment: The choice of a contextually appropriate `a` for various applications might not be trivial, but that's not the question we're answering. Doing what is being asked is most certainly trivial, with the task purely being to make sure that the first two coordinates of the second curve line up with the last two coordinates of the first curve.

Answer (score 0):

We can put all curves in an array then loop over them, moving to the last point before you draw the next bezier curve. Below is a sample code:

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="600" height="150"></canvas>
<script>
    var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    function drawCurve(x, y, curves) {
        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(x, y);
        for (i = 0; i < curves.length; i++) {
            c = curves[i]
            context.bezierCurveTo(c[0], c[1], c[2], c[3], c[4], c[5]);
            context.moveTo(c[4], c[5]);
            context.stroke();
        }
    }

    context.strokeStyle = 'blue';
    drawCurve(0, 150, [
        [100, 0, 200, 100, 300, 50],
        [400, 0, 500, 100, 600, 20]
    ]);

    context.strokeStyle = 'red';
    drawCurve(0, 10, [
        [100, 0, 180, 90, 280, 50],
        [400, 0, 400, 80, 600, 120]
    ]);
    
    context.strokeStyle = 'green';
    drawCurve(0, 80, [
        [100, 0, 90, 45, 140, 25],
        [200, 0, 200, 40, 300, 50],
        [500, 60, 400, 80, 300, 120],
        [300, 120, 200, 160, 100, 80],
    ]);
</script>
```

But the "unsmooth line" also depends on your curves, if they are in completely opposite directions we will see a sharp edge.

See the example below I'm drawing sort of a star.

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="150" height="150"></canvas>
<script>
  var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

  function drawCurve(x, y, curves) {
    context.moveTo(x, y);
    for (i = 0; i < curves.length; i++) {
      c = curves[i]
      context.bezierCurveTo(c[0], c[1], c[2], c[3], c[4], c[5]);
      context.moveTo(c[4], c[5]);
    }
    context.stroke();
  }

  data = []
  numPoints = 12
  size = 35
  angle = 45
  for (j = 0; j < numPoints; j++) {
    a = angle * Math.PI / 180
    points = []
    points.push(80 + Math.round(size / 2 * Math.sin(a)))
    points.push(80 + Math.round(size / 2 * Math.cos(a)))
    points.push(80 + Math.round(size * Math.sin(a)))
    points.push(80 + Math.round(size * Math.cos(a)))
    points.push(80 + Math.round(size * 2 * Math.sin(a)))
    points.push(80 + Math.round(size * 2 * Math.cos(a)))

    angle += 360 / numPoints
    data.push(points)
  }
  drawCurve(80, 80, data);
</script>
```